Django, Allegro API, error with get data form endpoint
I have problems with getting data after authorization, I can get main categories, but when a want get orders from account its display it:

{'errors': [{'code': 'EMPTY_USER_ID', 'message': 'User name from JWT cannot be empty', 'details': None, 'path': '/order/events', 'userMessage': 'User name from JWT cannot be empty', 'metadata': {}}]}

CLIENT_ID = settings.ALLEGRO_CLIENT_ID
CLIENT_SECRET = settings.ALLEGRO_CLIENT_SECRET
TOKEN_URL = "https://allegro.pl.allegrosandbox.pl/auth/oauth/token"

def get_access_token(request):
    try:
        data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
        access_token_response = requests.post(TOKEN_URL, data=data, verify=True,
                                             allow_redirects=False, auth=(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
        access_token_response.raise_for_status()
        tokens = json.loads(access_token_response.text)
        access_token = tokens['access_token']

        request.session['access_token'] = access_token
        return access_token
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        raise SystemExit(err)
def offers(request):
    url = 'https://api.allegro.pl.allegrosandbox.pl/order/events'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {get_access_token(request)}',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json',
    }
    response = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    print(response)
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'events':response})

I tried asking chat, and doing it with allegro API tutorials, but I don't know what is happened.
I just want to get orders from my account and display.
